# How can I create twisted geometry?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have attached an image as an example below. I want to twist a rectangle. Do I have to convert that rectangle into a curve or into mesh and then twist it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>?

Please explain with an example.

[image: desired result]

[image: my rectangular mesh]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Using *PROPORTIONAL EDITING* (with Linear Falloff type)

Add a *plane* , scale it along Z axis and divide it with many edge loops (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). Select the top edge and snap the cursor to it. Enable the ***proportional editing***, set the *falloff type* to ***Linear***. Now increase the influence circle with the <kbd>Mouse Scroll</kbd> and rotate (<kbd>R</kbd>) until you get the desired segments size.
[image]

## Using *SIMPLE DEFORM (BEND) and ARRAY modifiers*

Add a *plane* and subdivide it as above. Go to *Object Mode* and add a ***Simple Deform Modifier***. Increase the *Deform Angle* to 360 degrees. Then add an ***Array Modifier***, increase the *Count* number and set the *Z relative offset* to *1.000*. You may add another *Array* to duplicate the segments along the X axis.

[image]

Apply *modifiers* when done. Finally *remove doubles*.

Comment: thanks i was doing the same but it was not twisting may be i follow ur steps as all above steps also simple and good.

Comment: I have followed all the step with different methods. But in the below method of simple deform in my .gif as u can c its not getting twisted. Can u plz go through and tell me where im going wrong

Comment: I guess you haven't applied the transformations before adding a modifier. Select your plane in *Object Mode*, then press **Ctrl+A-->Apply Loc, Rot, Scale**. It should work now :).

Comment: Nice one. I'll add that if you enable *Merge* and *First Last* on that first Array Modifier you won't need to Remove Doubles after applying it. Each array iteration's "first" vertices will be merged into the "last" vertices of the iteration preceding it.

Answer (score 17):

You can easily achieve this with a Bezier curve object and the *Tilt* property

[image: Ribbons]

Just add two new bezier curves, one small used as *Bevel Object* and another one to use as a twisted ribbon.

Set the *Bevel Object* to the ribbon curve from the *Properties Window > Object Data (curve) > Geometry > Bevel Object*

Enter *Edit Mode* on the curve, and twist it by changing all handle types to *Automatic* (<kbd>V</kbd>), then select only one end vertex and tilt it by $360º$ either from the Space Bar menu or from the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

You can then repeat the pattern with an array modifier if you need no variations, or manually to add some randomness. Adjust curve segments as necessary if your geometry is not smooth enough.

[image: Twisted Ribbon Curve tilt]

It is advised to actually tilt the curve $360º$ instead of just $180$º, since rotating only half a turn will make the normals inconsistent at the ends, creating a visible seam and preventing geometry from welding seamlessly.

Comment: Nice gif- so hypnotizing  O.o. Oh, and thanks for reminding me a *Tilt* option.

Comment: Hahah thanks that was mostly just for fun ;). If you like that you'll probably love the [work of David Ope](http://dvdp.tumblr.com/) with awesome animated gifs

Comment: thanks for the beautiful animation. Can i extrude and make the Bezier hanging type and use. And adding to the material. Sorry im weak in node to make material. What paper material should i use

Comment: Edited the answer above with more details. Yes, you can make the curve extruded from one end so as to look as if it was hanging, you can even deform the curve to bend with weight instead of using an array. If you need physics however you better use the solution bellow by Paul Gonet instead. The paper material is a whole different business, please open a new question about it.