# How to twist a mesh for cloth-like effect?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh

I would like to create geometry and model it (not sculpt it), as to have a cloth-like effect, wrapped around a blade's handle (reference image shows this).

[image]
How would I go about doing this? When I attempt to do so, twisting a plane, or a cube, provides certain "artefacts" due to the fact that the rotation is alongside the Z axis for 180 degrees (out of logical reasons, having to align everything perfectly).

To summarise: How do I twist a mesh as to create the overlapping cloth effect?

Issue seen here: [image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/how-can-i-create-twisted-geometry

Comment: Thank you, @PaulGonet, I will shortly provide an answer to my issue, in case there are those which are specifically looking for this effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to emulate a ribbon (/twisted cloth-like effect) through these steps:

1. Create a **plane**, rotate it on the X axis by 90 degrees. (Front Ortho View)
2. Add a multitude of **loop cuts** to the plane from left to right (10-20) (Edit Mode)
3. Choose the top edge, then selected **Snap Cursor to Active**. (Spacebar, search for it.)
4. "O" key enables **Proportional Editing**, with the falloff type **"Linear"**.
5. Rotate the mesh from active, using the mouse scroll wheel to change the intensity, alongside whichever axis you desire. (Z axis in this instance)

Answer courtesy of: [How can I create twisted geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/how-can-i-create-twisted-geometry) (@Paul Gonet)

(Feel free to edit this to include images if necessary.)