# Is it possible to use Tilt in Bevel Object in a BezierCircle so that it rotates a full 360 degree through the circle uniformly?

Tags: bevel, bezier-curves

Sorry I wasn't quite sure how to word the question - There are two parts to the question, the first in the title, and the second in regards to multiple shapes (curves) being rotated.

[image: Bevel Object]

What I want to be able to do is eventually have the square pattern rotate slowly through 360 degrees as it follows the path through the Beziercircle so that the pattern twists around itself in two different ways (separately):

1: All 3 squares share a central point of rotation

2: Each square has its own individual point of rotation

Using Ctrl + T to enter tilt mode seems to split the bezier curve into two halves. That and I have to manually adjust each lever (Here it is at 0 90 180 270). Is there no semi-automated process of which I can input a formula, or some kindof instruction in the variables that tells the cubes to rotate a full 360 degrees during the orbit instead of splitting the circle in half?

[image: SplitCircle]

I also intend on working with several hundred if not more shapes at the same time so having a separate beziercurve / beziercircle for each shape is not ideal.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/how-can-i-create-twisted-geometry and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/logarithmic-curve-with-spiralling-cross-section/

Comment: These solutions seem to work for a linear beziercurve, but not for a circular one. It also doesn't answer the second part of the question. It's certainly closer to what I want but Is there any way to get the required result.

Comment: Each square can't have it's own rotation inside the same curve, create three separate sections and three separate bevel objects, one for each, or share bevel objects and adjust positions

Comment: Oh I see, that might become an issue when I need to do the same for several hundred objects at the same time...