How to I prevent this cusp on my curve with object profile?


In the first render you see a path, which is just a bezier circle. It has a curve object profile, which is 4 curve circles. The blue cube then follows the animated curve path. I use a 180 degree tilt which causes sharp cusps. Is there a better workflow to achieve the "marble" rollercoaster effect? I tried proportional editing method, but that didn't work.
Blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zQcBuGFO3G1awkXzSrrYcifiRAEjI5Ux/view?usp=sharing

Related, but without answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133804/is-it-possible-to-use-tilt-in-bevel-object-in-a-beziercircle-so-that-it-rotates

The root cause is that the tilt is interpolated between control points. It is not an issue for non cyclic curves. But for cyclic curves, the last value is not used, and the first value is used instead. So there is a linear interpolation between the penultimate and the first values. So if the tilt goes from 0°, to 90°, to 180°, to 270° over a circle with 4 control points, the tilt of the last segment is decreasing from 270° to 0°, instead of increasing from 270° to 360°. Would you be OK with a GeometryNodes modifier, instead of the Geometry>Bevel panel ?

@StefLAncien geo node setup would be fine. Maybe such a steep increase in twist is causing the issue? My real project will be more like a marble rollercoaster but I wanted to deal with the obstacle on a smaller track first.

(Using Blender 4.2.5)

In the proposed approach, GeometryNodes modifiers are used:

to setup the circular path,
to build the rails,
to animate the location and the rotation of the cube faces.


Circle GeometryNodes modifier
This graph controls the shape and the tilt of the circular path. It is attached to the default "Cube" object, renamed "Midline". It replaces the original "BézierCircle" curve and its modifications in Edit Mode.
For the demonstration, the tilt is going from $0$ to $2\pi$ along the curve (see the Multiply math node). Its evolution is edited through Float Curve nodes. The bottom node is providing a linear variation, while the top node is restricting the variation around 0. It is to notice that for a smooth transition at both ends of the circle, the slope must be the same at both ends of the tilt curve.
Bevel GeometryNodes modifier
This graph builds the rails. It is attached to an other "Cube" object, renamed "Rails". It replaces the Object Data Properties > Geometry > Bevel panel of the original "BézierCircle" curve.
Follow Path GeometryNodes modifier
This graph moves the vertices of the object to which it is attached (beware that it is no moving the object itself because its origin, scale and rotation remain unmodified). It replaces the original Follow Path constraint attached to the "Cube" object.
The Factor along the curve is computed from the current Frame to span the [0:1] interval. A Sample Curve node is providing the Position of the cube center, as well as its orientation through the Tangent and the Normal to the curve. The cube rotation is computed with Align Rotation to Vector nodes, aligning its X local axis with the Tangent and its Z local axis with the Normal. The cube Translation and Rotation are applied to its vertices using a Transform Geometry node.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.5+)
