# Modelling a twist like this procedurally

Tags: modeling, modifiers, procedural

I'm trying to achieve more or less this kind of twist on a model, but I want to do it procedurally rather than by hand. How would I go about this?

Picture for reference:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far? Screw modifier seems well suited for this.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65633

Comment: @JachymMichal I read somewhere on the forum that Simple deform modifier could be used. But I'm not getting the results I need at all :/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This is an example on a plane not on a cylinder... My geometry breaks when I try  this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggested, you can use Simple Deform modifier for this

1. One modifier set to *Twist* for the spiral
2. Angle around 1080° for three twists, and use limits to move it up/down
3. Second modifier set to *Taper*, and adjust to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks! Yeah I'm able to do this, but I was wondering if I could apply this on the model that I already have,  which say is not in such a simple shape and it would be a wast to just remodel it all again... Could I apply this simple deform only on certain vertices in a way that would end up looking like this?

Comment: Hey :). Yes, you can limit the influence on a vertex group. But hard to say how it's gonna turn out without seeing your mesh :).